# How to dispose an object only when number of references is zero

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a `Director` that supplies Builders to Threads.
Once an event is fired I need to dispose the Builder as it holds native resources BUT only when all Threads are done.

I keep the builders in a Cache so it's possible to think of it as to Dispose when number of references is zero if the director release the Builder.

I know about the circular references problem and It's not relevant in this scenario because only the `Director` supplies the references.

I know that I should implement the `Finalize`,`SuppressFinalize` pattern to avoid memory leak if thread died before disposing the `Builder`.

Consider the following example where its hard to tell who should actually dispose the builder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var builderId = 1;
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyBuilder> {{builderId, new MyBuilder()}};

            var director = new Director(dictionary);
            for (var i =0 ; i < 5; i++)
            {
                new Worker(director.GetBuilder(builderId));
            }
            director.Dispose(builderId);

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }

    public class Director
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<int, MyBuilder> _cache;

        public Director(Dictionary<int, MyBuilder> cache)
        {
            this._cache = cache;
        }

        public MyBuilder GetBuilder(int i)
        {
            MyBuilder builder;
            _cache.TryGetValue(i, out builder);
            return builder;
        }

        public void Dispose(int i)
        {
            MyBuilder builder;
            _cache.TryGetValue(i, out builder);
            builder?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class MyBuilder :IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Should I dispose?");
        }

        public void Build()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Build");
        }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        public void Work(MyBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Build();
            builder.Dispose();
        }

        public Worker(MyBuilder builder)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() => Work(builder));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems quite a low-level approach, and you may be reinventing the wheel. Have you had a look at [the Dataflow part of the Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)? That might have some higher-level approaches that would be more appropriate.

Comment: You can't get the number of references from the .NET framework so if you need something like this you need to add in the required functionality yourself. The question is, do you *need* it? Won't a finalizer, as you've already hinted, be enough?

Comment: Also, why are you reimplementing things already present in .NET? There's quite good constructs around tasks and PLinq, as well as Dataflow. Do you *need* to do anything at all?

Comment: Since your builder implements IDispose, could you wrap it in a using statement...     using (builder) { builder.Build()};

Comment: Note: A finalizer can only be used to free unmanaged resources - you can't (safely) use it to call `Dispose()` (other than when using the Dispose pattern to call `Dispose(false)`).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen A finalizer is not enough. I have to free the resources when triggered.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the tip, I will look in to that. Can you point the relevant approach?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen About the last comment. What am I re-implementing. Consider that this code is just a demo and the Workers are just for the example. I am looking for .NET support.

Comment: @DolevGamzo I don't really know enough about your actual requirements to suggest something, but perhaps look at the [Producer/Consumer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Any code in 2017 that uses threads sets of alarmbells in my mind to be honest :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and Matthew Watson, I appreciate your comments and changed my design. Thank you for the good tips!